# packaging node js code gives phantom js warning

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I need to generate a PDF which contains graph in node js server side . I have used d3js server side concept inorder to create an svg. svg2png npm library helps in converting svg to image and am amble to get graph in PDF. Now i need to create exe for the node js code where i am getting phantom js warning

This is the warning Im getting:

> Warning Cannot include file %1 into executable.
>     The file must be distributed with executable as %2.
>     node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs
>     path-to-executable/phantom/phantomjs
>   Warning Cannot include file %1 into executable.
>     The file must be distributed with executable as %2.
>     node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe
>     path-to-executable/phantom/phantomjs.exe

exe is getting created. But exe is not converting svg to png. How can i solve this warning???

This is my code for converting svg to png

```
const fs = require("pn/fs"); // https://www.npmjs.com/package/pn
const svg2png = require("svg2png");

fs.readFile("source.svg")
.then(svg2png)
.then(buffer => fs.writeFile("dest.png", buffer))
.catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Any help will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to compile as an executable? A quick peruse of the dependencies of [svg2png](https://github.com/domenic/svg2png/blob/master/package.json#L19-L23) shows `phantomjs-prebuilt`, which is basically an executable program. There are in fact quite a lot of "modules" on npm which actually simply "launch external programs" and gather the output. This basically looks like one of those, and hence the issue with attempting to compile an "executable" into your own "executable". Perhaps you should consider than not compiling as executable might be a good thing.

Comment: Im using pkg comment to compile as an executable. So it seems like i cannot compile it to exe.  @Neil Lunn

Comment: Any updates on this issue please?, I'm facing exactly the same problem.